# How much matrix differentiation background for Seber and Lee's Linear Regression Analysis

Tags: self-study, references

How self-contained is Seber & Lee's textbook 'Linear Regression Analysis'? It seems to assume knowledge of matrix differentiation.

Comment: I found the text to be more self-contained than others. Proofs are easier to follow than other books (to me) and some steps are left to the Appedix. The required matrix differentiation steps are given in the Appendix and there were not that many.

Comment: @julieth Thank you. On an unrelated note, why do you answer in a comment rather than in an 'answer'? I don't quite understand the etiquette here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seber & Lee's text have an appendix that contains everything that is used in the book, but with few proofs.  Matrix differentiation is used in the book, but not much, and is in the appendix.  I would have liked it even better if it contained something like what I wrote [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198257/intuition-for-the-product-of-vector-and-matrices-xtax/198280#198280).